# JToolBar/JMenu position overlap

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenu, jtoolbar

I am trying to put on a `JMenu` and `JToolbar` in the `NORTH` position of a `JFrame` but they overlap each other. Is there any way to put both on `NORTH` position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't attempt to add both components to the NORTH of the frame.

The frame reserves a special location for the menu bar. So your code should be somethink like:

```
frame.setJMenuBar( menuBar );
frame.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.